# EF Core updating shadow properties collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

When I'm trying to update my base model like this:

```cs
appContext.BaseQuestions.Update(question);
await appContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I'm getting an error:

> The value of shadow key property 'Question.Formulas#FormulaInfo.Id' is unknown when attempting to save changes. This is because shadow property values cannot be preserved when the entity is not being tracked. Consider adding the property to the entity's .NET type. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-owned-collections for more information.

My base class:

```cs
public class BaseQuestion
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Header { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool IsSolved { get; set; }           
    public Question? Question { get; set; }      
}
```

Subclass with shadow properties collection:

```cs
public class Question
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }          
    public string QuestionBody { get; set; }
    public Guid? BaseQuestionId { get; set; }
    public BaseQuestion? BaseQuestion { get; set; }     
    public ICollection<FormulaInfo>? Formulas { get; set; }
}
```

Base question configuration:

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<BaseQuestion> builder)
{
    builder
       .HasKey(bq => bq.Id);

    builder
        .Property(bq => bq.Id)
        .ValueGeneratedNever();   

    builder
        .Navigation(bq => bq.Question)
        .AutoInclude();

    builder
        .HasOne(bq => bq.Question)
        .WithOne(q => q.BaseQuestion)
        .HasForeignKey<Question>(q => q.BaseQuestionId)
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);            
}
```

Question configuration :

```cs
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Question> builder)
{
    builder
        .HasKey(q => q.Id);           

    builder
        .Property(q => q.Id)
        .ValueGeneratedNever();

    builder
       .Navigation(q => q.BaseQuestion)
       .AutoInclude();

    builder.OwnsMany(q => q.Formulas, f =>
    {
        f.WithOwner().HasForeignKey("OwnerId");
        f.Property<Guid>("Id");
        f.HasKey("Id");
    });
```

I just found examples of how to update a single shadow property but didn't find an ywith their collection. What should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: It looks like you have a Formula owned entity with a shadow property for it's Id column? I think the issue would be resolved just by declaring the Id property in the Formula entity. I don't see why you'd shadow that when both Question and BaseQuestion expose their Ids.